# Lost VSTS source control bindings in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Visual Studio 2015
Visual Studio 2013
Until recently used TFS for source control with Microsoft live id with my yahoo email.
Recent transition from TFS to VSTS.

Couple weeks ago devops switched my VSTS account to use company email instead of yahoo email.
After that in VS I couldn't use source control anymore,
was getting error: "TF30063: You are not authorized to access usga.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection."
and not being able to bind to source control.
Devops removed my company-email-account and reactivated my yahoo-email-account
and source control in VS started to work again, and with VSTS now.

I have not used Visual Studio for a week or so.
Today I discovered that:

My solutions lost Source Control Bindings.
I can Not bind my solutions to Source Control Again in Visual Studio.
When I re-bind it tells me that status is 'invalid'.
I do Not get any other errors.
Happens for all solutions that used to work fine with source control.
I seem to have access to www.visualstudio.com -> mycompany.visualstudio.com
and can see my projects there.

Please help me to undestand what is going on and rebind.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be a cache related issue, try to [delete VS and TFS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) cache and restart VS.

Also try to **remove** your account info which stored in **Credential Manager** （*Control Panel-All Control Panel Items-Credential Manager-Windows Manager*）

[image]

Then reconnect to VSTS in Visual Studio use your personal account, make sure selected the used workspace, get latest; or directly delete the old workspace, create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, but "delete VS and TFS" cache link you send me calls this approach “drastic” route when personal environment resets to default and many, if not all, the Visual Studio extension  have to be re-installed.
Team Foundation Server and Collection configuration evaporates during the user data reset. I would like to avoid this route if possible.

Comment: Hi @KarenSlon  Any update on this, have your issue been solved? Actually the source control binding is exist on the server, so there maybe something wrong with your local environment. Even rest you environment is a litter "drastic", but it should be the simple, effective way  out of the deadlock .

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved the following way:
1. when I've started to use TFS four years ago, I've created Microsoft Live Id account using my Personal email

2. this year when our devops were switching us from TFS to VSTS 
   they have tried to enforce rule of everybody to use their Office email for MS Live Id account. So they have created new account for me with Office email
3. Then I have described issues
4. Problem was resolved by switching me back to using original MS account with my Personal email.

And

5. I had to delete existing workspaces in Visual Studio 2015 
   and create new ones for my solutions to rebind code to VSTS.
   For some reason I had to repeat this process few times.

Hope it helps